# Doctrine 2: Insert with to-many relation: referenced row is not inserted

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I have two entities A and B with A having many Bs (Unidirectional Many-To-Many from A to B).
When creating a new A and assigning Bs to it, a constraint on the join table fails because doctrine is trying to insert associations with ID `0` for the new A. This leads me to believe that the INSERT for the new A has not been executed then.

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="a")
 */
class A {
    /**
     * @var int
     * @Id @Column(type="integer") @GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;
    /**
     * @var B[]
     * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="B", fetch="LAZY")
     * @JoinTable(name="jointable",
     *     joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="a_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *     inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="b_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $bs;

    public function getBs() { return $this->bs; }
}

// I omit B here, because it is not important

// controller code:
$a = new A();
$a->getBs()->add($em->find(B::class, 8));
$em->persist($a);
$em->flush();
```

And this is the error i am getting:

```
An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO jointable (a_id, b_id) VALUES (?, ?)' with params [0, 8]:

SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation...
```

Looking at the Database (and the Query-Log), the A is never created. As a result, the association to the B #8 fails.

How i can make doctrine get this right?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out doctrine did everything correct. The issue is this PHP Bug i reported: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71059

To compensate for it using Doctrine, you have two options:

### Override the boolean type

If all boolean fields in your DB are TINYINTs (as it is for me), you can simple override the boolean type:

```
Type::overrideType(Type::BOOLEAN,    \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TinyintBooleanType::class);
```

### Add custom type for TINYINT booleans

If not all boolean fields in your DB are TININTs, you have to add a new type to doctrine:

```
Type::addType(
    \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TinyintBooleanType::NAME,
    \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TinyintBooleanType::class
);

$entityManager->getConnection()->getDatabasePlatform()->registerDoctrineTypeMapping(
    Type::SMALLINT, \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\TinyintBooleanType::NAME
);
```

You can then use this type in Entities like so:

```
@Column(type="tinyintasbool")
```

### Source of TinyintBooleanType

```
<?php
namespace Doctrine\DBAL\Types;

use Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform;

/**
 * This type is appropriate when storing boolean values in TINYINT columns.
 * @author Tobias Marstaller
 */
class TinyintBooleanType extends Type
{
    const NAME = "tinyintasbool";

    public function convertToDatabaseValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        if ($value === null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else return $value? 1 : 0;
    }

    public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $patform)
    {
        if ($value === null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else return ((int) $value) === 0? false : true;
    }

    /**
     * Gets the SQL declaration snippet for a field of this type.
     *
     * @param array $fieldDeclaration The field declaration.
     * @param \Doctrine\DBAL\Platforms\AbstractPlatform $platform The currently used database platform.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSQLDeclaration(array $fieldDeclaration, AbstractPlatform $platform)
    {
        return $platform->getSmallIntTypeDeclarationSQL($fieldDeclaration);
    }

    /**
     * Gets the name of this type.
     *
     * @return string
     *
     * @todo Needed?
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return static::NAME;
    }

    public function getBindingType()
    {
        return \PDO::PARAM_INT;
    }
}
```